# Azure Search - SearchMode : ANY - not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

Fields (All fields are filterable)

```
DocumentName : string
Document_types : ['type1','type2','type3']
Date : Date
```

I'm using .net library in order to make calls to Azure Search API.

Example A (ANY) - I want to get all the results where keyword is `Text` or Document_types is `type1`.

How would this work? below is the sample code which I'm using.

```
        var filters = new SearchParameters()
        {
            Filter = "document_types/any(t: search.in(t, 'type1'))",
            Skip = (1 - 1) * 99999999,
            Top = 99999999,
            IncludeTotalResultCount = true,
            OrderBy = new[] { "as_of_date desc" },
            HighlightFields = new[] { "Content" },
            HighlightPreTag = "<span class=\"search-highlight\">",
            HighlightPostTag = "</span>",
            QueryType = QueryType.Full,
            SearchMode = SearchMode.Any
        };
        var results = await indexClient.Documents.SearchAsync("/.*" + query + ".*/", filters);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked with the use of `search.ismatch('{0}')`function.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for [Filters in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-filters) states that "A filter scopes a search query to a subset of documents"
i.e. we cannot have an `Or` condition between filter and search types. The solution/workaround is to convert the search text to a filter type using search.ismatch.

to get all the results where keyword is Text or Document_types is type1, change the Filter value to:

`Filter = "Document_types/any(t: search.in(t, 'type1') or search.ismatch('Text')",`

and call SearchAsync as

`var results = await indexClient.Documents.SearchAsync("", filters);`

Please note that this works only if the searchcriteria is not an empty string, as search.in doesn't accept empty string as its first parameter.

Comment: change `document_types` to `Document_types`

Comment: `search=""$filters=search.ismatchscoring('Text') OR Document_types/any(t: search.in(t, '38')&highlight=Content&HighlightPreTag=<mitesh>&HighlightPostTag=</mitesh>`   I have tried this as well, it returns OR as text search results in highlights.

Comment: Try `search=*&$filters=Document_types/any(t: search.in(t, 'type1') or search.ismatch('Text')`

Comment: it is returning results which is more than the actual records.

Comment: Add `$count=true` like `search=*&$filters=Document_types/any(t: search.in(t, 'type1') or search.ismatch('Text')&$count=true` to see the result count. Could you check the results and find out what are the result records that were not expected?